# TTImageview requestDidFinishLoad is called only after swipe

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, three20

I have a `TTImageview` in my app. I assign it with proper url:

```
myImage.urlPath = @"http://shoppa.itiul.co.il/Media/StoreImages/40/40_276x186.jpg";
```

But the image is not shown (`requestDidFinishLoad` is not called) until I swipe the screen.

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance,

Luda

Comment: More code please, this one isn't very useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: I have overridden the viewWillAppear method in the controller that uses the  TTImageview but forgot to call the super method.